# Connecting to unix socket inside docker container using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, unix-socket

I have written an app which connect to an already created unix.sock file and get some data from it. But I am getting EACCES error while try to connect. Error message is given below.

```
{ Error: connect EACCES /home/unix.sock
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
  errno: 'EACCES',
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/home/unix.sock' }
```

code snippet.

```
var socket = net.createConnection("/home/unix.sock")
          .on("connect", function() {
            console.log("Connected");
            socket.write(req1);
            socket.write(req2);
          })
          .on("data", function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log("Response from server: %s", data.response);
            // Close the connection
            socket.end();
          })
          .on('error', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
          })
```

Any idea about why this error occurs? I think it is because of the non root container. Is there anyway I can get rid of this error with non root container?

Comment: Please check Sockets Error mentioned [here](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/837#issuecomment-64104765). Also [this](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html#ERRORS)

Comment: What's on the server side of the socket?  How does it get into the container filesystem?  What are its permissions, and are they compatible with the user the process is running as?

Comment: Bindmounting the volume. I mounted the path which have the socket to /home/ folder